# node.js with express routing to a new page within socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a button on a page that when it is clicked, i want the page to call some node.js server code.  I have this wired up via socket.io.  The issue I am running into is I need the socket.io code to redirect my web page based on some business logic.  Not sure what is the best way to do that via express (res.redirect?) and also how to get access to that within the socket.io call.  Any help would be appreciated!

App.js

```
var dashboard = require('./middleware/dashboard.js');
...
app.get("/dashboard", function (req, res) {
    dashboard.show(req, res);
});
...
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.set('log level',2); // sets socket io log level 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info, 3=debug
...
dashboard.wireUpSocketIO(io);
...
```

dashboard.js

```
var savedResponse;

exports.show = function(req, res) {
    savedResponse = res;
    res.render("dashboard.jade"});
};


exports.wireUpSocketIO = function(io){
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('dashboardOnButtonClick', function(msg) {

            <biz logic>

             savedResponse.render("someOtherPage.jade", {
                    locals: {
                        title: "someOtherPage",
                        filter: msg.filter
                    }
             });
        });
    });
}
```

dashboard.jade

```
button#btnFilter(class='btn btn-info') Test Button

script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
script .
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  var emitMessage = { blah: false, filter:"n/a"};

  $('#btnFilter').click(function(){
      emitMessage.blah = true;
      emitMessage.filter = "filterByBlah";
      socket.emit('dashboardOnButtonClick', emitMessage);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could think it is easier to do from the client side, that is, javascript:

1. Once the server side logic is done, you send a message back to the client and change the `window.location` to the new one.
2. Once the server is done, the client can issue a request to that the server will respond with a HTTP 301/302 Redirect. This way you can call res.Redirect on that Express request.

Regards,

Comment: Is that safe when web render a new page in client-side?

Comment: @KammerLee I don't why it shouldn't, maybe you want to elaborate on your concerns?